# Custom validation for a simple directive that transcludes an input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular directive that looks like this

```
foo.directive('inputFoo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<input type='text' ng-model='argument.value'/>",
    transclude: true,
    controller: [
      '$scope', '$attrs', function($scope, $attrs) {
        if ($attrs.hasOwnProperty('value')) {
          return $scope.argument.value = $attrs.value;
        }
      }
    ]
  };
});
```

That I want to write a custom validation for. Is it better to write an entire new directive that I then include in the template e.g

```
template: "<input type='text' custom-validation ng-model='argument.value'/>",
```

Or should I add a link function to inputFoo that handles validation?